# I want to change class of Hyper link when i hover around the section which it is linked

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I implement javascript for the code below that adds class="active" to hyper link when I move to the section, i.e when I move to section it should add class="active" to About.
And also if I move to other section remove the class="active" from previous section and Add to the current section.

```css
#s1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(156, 78, 192);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#s1 h1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
#s2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(187, 82, 40);
}
#s3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(58, 56, 168);
}
#s4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(78, 54, 54);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#s1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#s2">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#s3">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#s4">Project</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section id="s1" id="top"><h1>hello</h1></section>
  <section id="s2"></section>
  <section id="s3"></section>
  <section id="s4">
    <a href="#top">goto top</a>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the click events in your nav and add/remove the 'active' class from the `<li` tags

```js
window.addEventListener('DomContentLoaded', () => { 
  // listen for the DOM to finish loading
  document.querySelectorAll('.nav li a').forEach(el => { 
  // get all the nav links together in a loop
    el.addEventListener('click', e => { 
    // listen for the click event on the nav item
      document.querySelectorAll('.nav li').forEach(li => li.classList.remove('active')); 
      // first remove all active classes from all navigation links
      e.target.closest('li').classList.add('active') 
      // apply active class to the chosen nav
    })
  })
})
```

```css
#s1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(156, 78, 192);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#s1 h1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

#s2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(187, 82, 40);
}

#s3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(58, 56, 168);
}

#s4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(78, 54, 54);
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  background: #000;
}

.active a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#s1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#s2">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#s3">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#s4">Project</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section id="s1" id="top">
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="s2"></section>
  <section id="s3"></section>
  <section id="s4">
    <a href="#top">goto top</a>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping!!. But Cany you provide me the reference to the event listeners of js

Comment: I added a link reference and commented the code in my updated answer. An event listener does just that - it 'listens' for an event. In this code there are 2 events being listened for. The first is listening for the `DomContentLoaded` event - that happens after the HTML of the page has been loaded in. We wait for that because without it, we would be running code on HTML that hasn't yet been loaded. The second listens for a 'click'

Comment: thanks kinglish for helping me in this problem.